# How do I write a "vector" with equations followed by a condition that is true for both in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, vector

[image]

How do I write the following in LaTeX? I would also need that it has the same equation number.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a do-it-for-me question that shows no evidence of research or attempts by the asker.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  This site isn't quite "ask any question you want", but is more aimed at people who know some TeX but are having trouble with a particular point.  I would encourage you to find some sort of introduction to TeX to help you learn the basics.  And if you already know the basics, then we would ask that you post what you have so far, instead of just an image.  That way we also have something to start from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the array environment:

```
\[
    \begin{array}{c}
        \mu(\alpha) = \alpha r + (1 - \alpha) \hat{\mu}\\
        \sigma(\alpha) = (1 - \alpha) \hat{\sigma}
    \end{array}
    ,\qquad \forall\alpha\le 1, 1 - \alpha\ge 0
\]
```

Change `\qquad` to some other spacing such as `\quad` or `\hspace` if you prefer and you can add more equations by ending each one with the new line marker, `\\`. Also if you change `c` to `l` or `r` you will have the equations align on the left or right respectively which may look nicer depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an numbered equation, I propose one of these solutions, based on the `empheq` package (a superset of `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[right={\qquad \forall\alpha\le 1, 1 - \alpha\ge 0} ]{equation}
      \begin{split} \mu(\alpha) & = \alpha r + (1 - \alpha) \hat{\mu},\\[0.5ex]
        \sigma(\alpha) & = (1 - \alpha) \hat{\sigma},
\end{split}
    \end{empheq}\bigskip

\begin{equation}
\begin{rcases}
\mu(\alpha) = \alpha r + (1 - \alpha) \hat{\mu},\\[0.5ex]
        \sigma(\alpha) = (1 - \alpha) \hat{\sigma},
\end{rcases}\enspace \forall\alpha\le 1, 1 - \alpha\ge 0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]